# Kubectl connectivity issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I installed first ectd, kubeapiserver and kubelet using systemd service. The services are running fine and listening to all required ports.

When I run kubectl cluster-info , I get below output

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
```

When I run kubectl get componentstatuses, then I get below output

```
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health": "true"}
```

But running kubectl get nodes , I get below error

```
Error from server (ServerTimeout): the server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again later (get nodes)
```

Can anybody help me out on this.

Comment: Have you used kubadm or manual istallation of Kubernetes cluster? If it was installed manually please put the link to instruction you have followed. Could you also check the kube-apiserver logs and kubelet service logs for errors?

Comment: I haven't followed such particular link. I read many docs and created the mentioned master components. My installation is manual.

Comment: Unfortunately, so many things can go wrong if you install the cluster manually. It's hard to guess how to fix the problem without detailed information what you've done and what is the current state of the cluster.

Comment: I reconfigured cluster using kubernetes the hardway documentation and below is the status of my cluster now

Answer (score 20):

For the message:

```
:~# k get cs
Warning: v1 ComponentStatus is deprecated in v1.19+
NAME                 STATUS      MESSAGE                                                                                       ERROR
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10252: connect: connection refused   
scheduler            Unhealthy   Get "http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10251: connect: connection refused   
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health":"true"} 
--------
```

Modify the following files on all master nodes:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
```

Comment or delete the line:

```
- --port=0
```

in (spec->containers->command->kube-scheduler)

```
$ sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
```

Comment or delete the line:

```
- --port=0
```

in (spec->containers->command->kube-controller-manager)

Then restart kubelet service:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart kubelet.service
```

Comment: Thank you Mustapha. Is restarting the kubelet necessary?

Comment: this fix the issue on my cluster but why commenting this line is needed? is it safe to comment it on production systems? thanks

Comment: error appears when upgrading from v1.8.20 to v1.19.13.
i am interested to know what's the root cause. But even no answer, i am ok as it works...
جزاك الله خيرا مصطفى

Comment: Please, just remember that this approach for sure will fix your issue, but will open the insecure port closed by the Kubernetes: https://docs.datadoghq.com/security_platform/default_rules/cis-kubernetes-1.5.1-1.2.19/

Answer (score 1):

Your missing kubeconfig file. kubectl looks config file in this location `$HOME/.kube/config`

Part of install you can copy config file like this on master node.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Comment: run this command `kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf  get pod` see it list the pods.

Answer (score 0):

What is the status of controller manager and scheduler. Do you see them listed as Healthy when you run the below command

```
kubectl get cs
```

Comment: I havent configured controller-manager and scheduler as of now

`root@ubuntu:~# kubectl get cs
scheduler            Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10251: getsockopt: connection refused
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10252: getsockopt: connection refused
etcd-1               Unhealthy   Get http://192.168.57.140:400/health: dial tcp 192.168.57.140:400: getsockopt: connection refused
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health": "true"}`

Comment: I wanted to list the etcd but I am not sure that do I need to configure controller-manager and scheduler to make kubectl get nodes work

Comment: Yes. Controller manager and scheduler should be setup else k8s doesn't work

Comment: I reconfigured cluster.
`root@ubuntu:~# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080

root@ubuntu:~# kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
127.0.0.1   Ready    <none>   119m   v1.12.0
root@ubuntu:~# kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
scheduler            Healthy   ok
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}`

Dont know why the Role of master is none.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I labed the node as master. Now I can see role as master